# Undefined control sequence align

Tags: alignment

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P_{loss}&=0.0015P_{1}+\0.0014P_{2}-0.0001P_{3}\\             

& +0.0009P_{4}-0.0004P_{5}    \label{eq}

\end{align*}
\end{document}'
```

Why is there an error on align? Undefined control seq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    P_{loss}&=0.0015P_{1}+0.0014P_{2}-0.0001P_{3}\\                 
    & +0.0009P_{4}-0.0004P_{5}    \label{eq}    
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You had an extra backslash in front of the 0.0014P_{2} that was messing things up; also you need to get rid of the extra blank line  between the two lines within the align environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.